# How to select a particular part of a string in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I use the function .html() to extract the html code, but I want to extract a particular part of the string.

```
var newImgAdr = $(this).html();
```

newImgAdr contains

```
<img class="thumbnail-holder image-responsive center-block lavatar" src="@routes.Assets.at("images/example/aungsansuukyi.jpg")" alt="@Messages("actor.label.pic.noimage")">
```

And I want to extract "images/example/aungsansuukyi.jpg". How can I do it without using slice()?

Comment: You could use regular expressions.

Comment: you can grab the entire `src` and then replace the non-required string with blank string to get image location.

Comment: Why are you using `.html()`when you're trying to fetch from an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions like this :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="thumbnail-holder image-responsive center-block lavatar" src="@routes.Assets.at('images/example/aungsansuukyi.jpg')" alt="@Messages('actor.label.pic.noimage')">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $src = $("img").attr("src");
                $patt = /(\b\(\')(.*)(\'\))/gi;
                $src.match($patt,"$2");
                alert(RegExp.$2);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match()` function for it.

```
var url = text.match(/@routes\.Assets\.at\("(.+)"\)/);
```

Then you can pull out the value from `url[1]`